# How to give my custom control an overridable default margin?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-3.5

**Problem**

I've created a custom control (OmniBox), which has its base style set with:

```
<Style x:Key="GridStyle" TargetType="Grid" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseElement}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,2" />
</Style>
```

But when I'm using my control, I want to be able to do something like:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ui:OmniBox}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,10"/> <!--Not Working?-->
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
     <StackPanel>
           <ui:OmniBox x:Name="One"... />
           <ui:OmniBox x:Name="Two"... />
           ...
```

And have all instances of my control take on that default margin. Unfortunately, my controls are not responding to the style set in the resources. They are just keeping their default margin of "0,2".

Strangely, if I explicitly set the margin on my controls like so:

```
           <ui:OmniBox x:Name="One" Margin="0,10" Style="OBDefaultStyle" ... />
           <ui:OmniBox x:Name="Two" Margin="0,10" ... />
           ...
```

They DO use the margin of "0,10" rather than "0,2". How come the template type isn't working?

If it's relevant, my OmniBox control templates all look like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:OmniBox}" x:Key="OBDefaultStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource OBDefaultTemplate}" />
</Style>
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:OmniBox}" x:Key="OBDefaultTemplate">
    <Grid x:Name="PART_Grid" Style="{StaticResource GridStyle}">
        ... (Content)
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

---

**First Attempt**

In my grid style, I've tried setting Margin to

```
<Setter Property="Margin" 
        Value="{Binding Path=Margin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:OmniBox}}}" />
```

But it didn't help in sucking down the templated margin.

**Second Attempt**

I tried creating a custom margin dependency property and binding the grid to that:

```
<Style x:Key="GridStyle" TargetType="Grid" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseElement}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{Binding Path=MyMargin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
</Style>
```

My custom property was defined as:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MarginProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Margin", typeof(Thickness), typeof(OmniBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new Thickness(0,2,0,2), new PropertyChangedCallback(OnMarginChanged)));
```

Anyways it didn't work. The default margin set in the dependency property above is still overriding the margin I'm trying to set in the style template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After happening on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653364/how-can-i-change-the-default-value-of-an-inherited-dependency-property), I figured out what I needed to do. In the control's class, I need to override the margin property's default value:

```
    static OmniBox()
    {
        MarginProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(OmniBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new Thickness(0,2,0,2)));
    }
```

After that, I get rid of the margin on the "Grid" component of the omnibox completely, since the control itself carries a margin. Now when the user sets the "Margin" property on the OmniBox, it accepts it, if they don't, it uses the default value.

Thank you all so much for your suggestions and effort.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a default style for a custom control by overriding the metadata for the DefaultStyleKey:

```
public class MyButton : Button
{
    static MyButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyButton)));
    }
}
```

You then create a resource dictionary called `Generic.xaml` that is located in a directory called `Themes` in the root of the project (so the path will be "/Themes/Generic.xaml"). In that resource dictionary you create a default style for your control:

```
<!-- Base the style on the default style of the base class, if you don't want to completely
     replace that style. If you do, remember to specify a new control template in your style as well -->
<Style TargetType="SomeNamespace:MyButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />    
</Style>
```

If you just add a `MyButton` control it will get the default style, but you can override properties set in the default style by applying a new style:

```
<Window x:Class="SomeNamespace.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:SomeNamespace="clr-namespace:SomeNamespace"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="SomeNamespace:MyButton">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <SomeNamespace:MyButton />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: +1 Hey, sorry I didn't really see what you were getting at until I stumbled onto the solution I posted, but this was the right general idea - using OverrideMetaData - I just wanted it specifically for the margin property. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you overridden the `DefaultStyleKey` property in your `OmniBox` control?

Comment: From what I can tell, there is no DefaultStyle property on my control, I'm certainly not referencing anything like it.

Comment: Did a quick search through MSDN and I can't find any such thing except in something called the [BaseValueSource Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.basevaluesource.aspx) which appears to have something to do with Dependency Properties :?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.defaultstylekey.aspx. Example is contained within. I should have said DefaultStyleKey rather than DefaultStyle.

Answer (score 1):

`GridStyle` specifies `TargetType="Grid"`, so the setter `<Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,2" />` applies to the `Grid` at the root of the control template. Setting the `Margin` property of the containing `OmniBox` has no effect of the margin of that grid.

Try specifying this in the template:

```
<Grid x:Name="PART_Grid" Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}">
```

Notice I did not set the `Style` property as you did in the template. This is because the grid's `Margin` property will always reflect the `Margin` property of the `OmniBox` containing it, negating the effect of the `Margin` property in `GridStyle`. Instead you will want to default the `OmniBox.Margin` property and remove `GridStyle` entirely:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:OmniBox}" x:Key="OBDefaultStyle">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 2" />
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource OBDefaultTemplate}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do away with the GridStyle entirely, it's full of other configurations. Is this supposed to work regardless? I'll try what you said about moving the default margin to the Omnibox style rather than the Grid within.

Comment: @Alain: You just need to remove the `Margin` setter from `GridStyle`. I only said you should remove the style entirely because that was the only setter in it in your question. Everything else should work fine.

Comment: When I do the above I get the compile error "'Margin' member is not valid because it does not have a qualifying type name". What's that all about?

Comment: @Alain: I made the assumption that `OmniBox` has the `Margin` property already defined (i.e. that it ultimately derives from FrameworkElement: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin.aspx). Please verify that the `Margin` property is defined on `OmniBox`; if not, please define it as you did in your question and try again.

Comment: Checked and it does have margin, inherits it from System.Windows.Controls.Control. If I re-define it, I get a warning that I'm hiding an inherited member, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I have never seen this before and I have done what you are trying to do many times. Can you strip your solution down to only the elements that are relevant here, and see if you get the error? Also, can you post the `OmniBox` style?

Comment: +1 I approached from a different angle and figured out something I could do in the control class itself rather than the xaml of the control templates. I really appreciate your time.