# Setter not working for margin on user control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a UserControl that is working just fine. If I set the margin in code all goes well:

```
<cbtn:BillLister Margin="10,5,10,5" />
```

However, when i try to set it for everyone of those that are in the wrappannel they are in, this doesn't work:

```
<WrapPanel.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="cbtn:BillLister">
    <Style.Setters>
      <Setter Property="Margin" Value="150,35,50,35" />
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
    </Style.Setters>
  </Style>
```

The Background property is working however, so i know that it is targeting the correct UserControls.

I did find this: [How to give my custom control an overridable default margin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759448/how-to-give-my-custom-control-an-overridable-default-margin)   I tried what he did in there, and still no change.

```
public partial class BillLister : UserControl
{
    public BillLister()
    {
        InitializeComponent();     
        Labelcount.Content = "0";
    }

    static BillLister()
    {
        MarginProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(BillLister), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new Thickness(30, 130, 30, 30)));            
    }
...
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on here? I would hate to have to set the margin on each one manually.

**Update to clarify:** When trying the second version i don't use the inline margin from the first one. Also, the margin fromthe second example is not applied at all.

Comment: When you try your second approach do you still have inline margin given Margin="10,5,10,5"?

Comment: No, it's to replace the inline one that i'm trying to do that.

Comment: With or Without the static constructor in the second one makes no difference.