# Trying to use AddOwner method in UserControl to pass SelectedDate through to embedded DatePicker

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I have a user control with an embedded DatePicker. I would like to pass some of the DatePicker properties through to the internal DatePicker control. It seems like I should be able to use AddOwner on the UserControl, but the defined OnSelectedDateChanged method never fires.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedDateProperty =
    DatePicker.SelectedDateProperty.AddOwner
    (
        typeof(MyUserControl), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits, 
        onSelectedDateChanged)
    );

private static void onSelectedDateChanged(DependencyObject o, 
                                          DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // my code here
}
```

To get it to work, I just defined a standard dependency property DateTime? SelectedDate on the UserControl and then pass the value in to the internal DatePicker.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN has a pretty good topic about [overriding Metadata for a Dependency Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754209.aspx).

You can also safely add an extra property changed handler, it will be 'merged' with the existing one. For detailed information about that look at the [`OverrideMetadata`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597491.aspx) documentation.

A more or less related answer can also be found here on StackOverflow: [How can I change the default value of an inherited dependency property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653364/how-can-i-change-the-default-value-of-an-inherited-dependency-property)